# Matrix Multiplication Sign Preservation

Tags: linear-algebra

If $Ax\geq b$, under what conditions on $K$ can I premultiply it and preserve the sign?
i.e

What is a sufficient condition on $K$ for:
$$KAx\geq Kb$$

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on what you mean by "$\ge$".

Comment: Component wise.

Comment: Are you sure you want a sufficient condition? One sufficient condition is that $K$ is the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have two vectors which satisfies the component-wise inequality (denoted $\ge_c$)
$$\mathbb{x} \ge_c \mathbb{y}$$
If you want a matrix such that
$$A\mathbb{x} \ge_c A\mathbb{y}$$
then that is equivalent to requiring
$$\mathbb{a_i}\cdot \mathbb{x} \ge \mathbb{a_i}\cdot \mathbb{y}$$
for each row vector $\mathbb{a_i}$ of $A$. It is sufficient (and probably necessary) that you require $A$ to be non-negative.

Comment: Can you show this? I think it is true but I need the proof, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = Ax-b$

Assume $A$ is full rank. Then your question is the condition for matrix $K$,  so that $Ky ≥_c 0,\ \forall y \geq_c 0 $

Necessary and sufficient condition for this, is non negativitity of $A$.

Comment: Can you show this? I think it is true but I need the proof, thanks